# Uncaught TypeError: Object 600 has no method 'substring'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to get the first and third character from a string using the following

```
function kFormatter(num) {
    return num > 999 ? (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K' : num
}
var AmountOrdered = Math.ceil($(this).val() / 100.0) * 100;
var formatAmountOrdered = kFormatter(AmountOrdered);
console.log(formatAmountOrdered.substring(0, 1));
```

Inside my **console log** I see the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 600 has no method 'substring'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the function to

```
function kFormatter(num) {
    return num > 999 ? (num/1000).toFixed(1)+'K' : ''+num
}
```

so that it always return a string.

Comment: @Curtis don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem so future visitors with the same issue will know what to try first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like substring is converted to `int` in your code. You need to convert it to `string`

```
var formatAmountOrdered = kFormatter(AmountOrdered) + '';
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that if the parameter `num` is not greater than 999, the function will return a numeric value, not a string.  Numeric values don't have a `substring` method.

You can modify the expression to always return a string by changing:

```
return num > 999 ? (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K' : num
```

to:

```
return num > 999 ? (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K' : num + ''
```